# Group by maximum excluding values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below input and wanted to get one value for each A. From the values in column 'RE' that are not equal to 'REV', get the max of them. If there are only REV values in column 'RE' for that particular 'A', then return 'REV'.

My Oracle version is 12.1

Input

```
A   RE
--  --
A1  REV
A1  C1
A1  C2
A2  REV
A2  REV
A2  C6
A3  REV
```

Expected output (the explanation column is not needed).

```
A   RES EXPLANATION
--  --- -----------
A1  C2  There are values C1 and C2 (excluding REV), so C2 is the max
A2  C6  There is just value C6 (excluding REV).
A3  REV There are no values other than REV.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation with `coalesce()`:

```
select a,
       coalesce( max(case when re <> 'REV' then re end),
                 max(re)
               )
from input
group by a;
```

The first `max()` gets the maximum of all non-REV rows.  The second returns the `max()` when all rows are `'REV'`.  You could actually replace it with `'REV'` as well.